# Archive Posts after set time with ruby and rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I want to archive (or delete) posts after 24hours. Is this possible ? when a user logs in after 24hours previous post will not be shown instead just the link to create a new post for the next 24hours. For now it does not matter if previous posts gets deleted but will love to learn to to do it both ways. cheers

Answer (score 1):

This would retrieve records less than 24 hours old...

```
 Post.where( 'created_at > ?', 1.day.ago )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve. Very simple solution.

Comment: Hi, sorry, mistyped (now fixed).  It's 1.day.ago (dot, not underscore)

Comment: Cheers Steve, how will this adjust to various time zones ?

Comment: the datetime is stored in universal time zone (UTC) and `1.day.ago` will calculated from universal time zone so regardless of in what time zone the post was created and regardless of what time zone the user is seaching for posts, `1.day.ago` will give you posts that were made in the previous 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without having to alter or destroy the data about the post is to use a scope on the record. For example, you could do something like:

```
scope :recent_posts, lambda { where("created_at <= ?", (Time.zone.now - 24.hours).to_s(:db)) }
```

A couple things to understand about this:

1. Any place you want to have only recent posts appear, you have to use the .recent_posts scope
2. The lambda is needed because this causes the current time (Time.now) to be evaluated at run time every time the scope is invoked; just doing a where with no lambda would make the evaluation of Time.now static and not change over time.
3. The .to_s(:db) ensures that the timestamp is formatted correctly for evaluation by the database.
4. It assumes you have timestamps on your posts table.
5. It is possible to apply a default_scope that is used for every query against the model except those where it is explicitly excluded. This is generally regarded as a bad practice because it's easy to make mistakes by not realizing a scope is being applied implicitly.

It is possible to truly archive records from your database. Without knowing what your table structure is it's hard to say exactly how to do it, but in general you have two types of options:
 1. Use a rake task that is scheduled to run periodically (like every night) that finds records that should be archived, creates the archive record in a new table and destroys the record in the active table. 
 2. Create logic within the database (like a stored procedure) that has logic similar to the above, and again use some kind of scheduler to trigger it.

The first is probably the easiest, most understandable way to do it, but is not performant for large datasets. The second would likely perform much better, but introduces additional complexity by putting some application code in Rails and other application code in your database tier.

Comment: Cheers Chris will git it a try.

Comment: Where exactly should this be placed ? and how is it called in the view. Sorry have not had much experience using scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [these](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby) [two](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised) Railscasts to learn about [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to schedule jobs.